# Make programmatically added fragment clickable, uniquely identifiable

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm running into some problems trying to figure out how to make fragments that I have programmatically added into a LinearLayout clickable. I'm using fragments because they will be in multiple activities and it was a good way for me to create a layout like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4lOG.png

But, if there's a better way to do this that would make the process of making it clickable, I'm certainly open to changing things up.

Anyway, I'm adding the fragments to the LinearLayout, jobsList, like so:

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    int count = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("jobID", i + 1);
        jobFragment job = new jobFragment();
        job.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.jobsList, job, Integer.toString(i));
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

The count of 2 is just a placeholder for now, later there will be an arbitrary number of jobs.

Here is the layout, it's a bit of a mess but I got all the specific weights the way I wanted this way.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".2" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/basicPort"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/background"
                    android:text="Port" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/basicLoadOrEmpty"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/background"
                    android:text="Load/Empty" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/basicInOrOut"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/background"
                    android:text="In/Out" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".6"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".333" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/basicContainerNum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                    android:background="@drawable/background"
                    android:text="Container #" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/basicChassisNum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                    android:background="@drawable/background"
                    android:text="Chassis #" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/basicContainerType"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:background="@drawable/background"
                    android:text="Cont. Type" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".333" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/basicDirectionArrow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".2"
                    android:background="@drawable/background"
                    android:text="Direction" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/basicCustomer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight=".8"
                    android:background="@drawable/background"
                    android:text="Customer Location" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".333" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/basicSteamshipLine"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".4"
                    android:background="@drawable/background"
                    android:text="Steamship Line" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/basicBKG_BOL"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".6"
                    android:background="@drawable/background"
                    android:text="BKG-BOL#" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".2" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/basicStatus1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/background"
                    android:text="Status 1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/basicStatus2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:background="@drawable/background"
                    android:text="Status 2" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My question to you is, is it possible to make these fragments clickable and uniquely identifiable, and if so, what is the best way to go about doing that?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What's your definition of "clickable?" That said, you can `setTag()` and `getTag()` to identify the Fragment. Anything inside your Fragment should be regular UI.

Comment: By clickable I mean when a specific fragment in the jobs list is tapped by the user, I would like a function to be called. Basically like a button's onClickListener but for a fragment.

Comment: Then make your Fragment's container element (likely a Layout of some sort?) clickable, create an interface to your Activity, and handle the click in there. Post your Fragment layout.

Comment: I added the layout to the OP. It's a bit of a mess, I'll admit.

Comment: You could probably get away with having this be a `ListView` rather than a Fragment, unless you plan on interacting with the individual items more. Regardless, I posted a general pattern on how to interact with Fragments.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working before even seeing the answer. And quite happy to have helped!

Comment: Well, I saw your previous tips and I had been working on it. I didn't realize you had replied with a different method. But yes, thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to follow up on things in case anybody stumbles upon this answer in the future. It turns out using fragments was a bad idea. While I was able to make them clickable and identifiable through a bit of a hack job, I ran into problems later on when I was trying to fix layout issues. So, thanks to @Rarw I looked into using a `LayoutInflater` instead.

And that was much easier! I just made the layout xml file, used the `LayoutInflater` to add it to a `LinearLayout` and added that to the list. Makes things much easier down the road:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(this);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.basic, container, true);
container.setId(i);
list.addView(container, params);
container.setClickable(true);
container.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: can you post the hack job on making the frags clickable and getting the ids?

Comment: @sirvon sorry, don't have it anymore. I changed that stuff before I added the project to git.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is:

1. Modify the layout of your fragment, so it uses the RelativeLayout (now its probably LinearLayout right?). By modify I mean either use RelativeLayout INSTEAD of LinearLayout (more complicated but i think a bit better), or put your LinearLayout INSIDE RelativeLayout.
2. Place a view that matches in size the size of the fragment, on top of your textViews. Add an onClickListener to it that performes the code on clicks.

Answer (score 0):

First - fragments are not clickable, layouts and their children are. A `Fragment` can handle the click action for things that occur in its layout but you do not "click" the fragment.

Second - sounds like you're confused about how to use fragments and what a `Fragment` actually does. A `Fragment` is like an `Activity` with some parts missing. A `Fragment` has its own lifecycle and can be used to perform many of the same tasks as an `Activity` the difference being that (1) a `Fragment` is "hosted" by an activity that provides the missing functions and does not run on its own (2) a `Fragment` can run in the background with no UI (I do not know of a background activity yet).

You do not need to/should not be using `Fragments` for what you are trying to do.

Your layout is really just a series of `TextView`s. You should be able to make that layout in XML reuse that layout file - by simply getting a `LayoutInflater` anywhere else in your app that you want to. If things got really crazy you could create a custom `TextView` class to provide detailed functionality but you should not be using 10 fragments, each with one `TextView` to make that layout work.

Comment: I'm just using one fragment, all the layout stuff is done with LinearLayouts. I'm not disputing the fact that I don't fully understand fragments, but it seemed the best way to go about designing this. I'll look into LayoutInflaters and see if that might be better.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky solution is to place a transparent button on top of the entire fragment, have the fragment extend onClickListener, and set the button's onClickListener to this.

One way to create such a button:
Use a constraintLayout as the root layout for the xml.
As the last of child of the constraintLayout, create a button, constrain it to occupy entire fragment by setting layout_constrainXXX to corner elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
<!-- The remaining properties of the layout -->

    <!-- All the children of the layout -->

    <Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_button" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note that you can do this other ways too, such as in a `RelativeLayout`

Then in the java/kotlin file, extend onClickListener.

```
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
    // Whatever you want to do here
    }
```

In method onActivityCreated, set the transparent button's listener as:

```
    var button : Button = fragment_button
    button.setOnClickListener(this)
```